# Structure of $\mathbb CG-$module of $Hom(U,V)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $U$ and $V$ two finite dimensional $\mathbb CG-$modules. Consider the vector space $Hom(U,V)$ of all linear transformations from $U\to V$. We make $Hom(U,V)$ into a $\mathbb CG-$module by setting $$(g\cdot \varphi)(u)=g\varphi(g^{-1}u)$$
for all $g\in G,\varphi\in Hom(U,V)$ and $u\in U$.

1) Show that indeed define a $\mathbb CG-$module structure on $Hom(U,V)$.

**Misunderstanding :** Could someone explain me what mean the question ? I don't understand what they want me to do.

2) Show that the natural map
\begin{align*}
\psi: U^*\otimes V&\longrightarrow Hom(U,V)\\
f\otimes v&\longmapsto  \varphi_{f,v}: u\longmapsto f(u)v
\end{align*}
define an $\mathbb C G-$ isomorphism.

**Question** I also problem with this. So I try to show that is linear, i.e. $$\psi(f\otimes v+ h\otimes w)=\psi(f\otimes v)+ \psi(h\otimes w)$$
but I don't see how to interpret $f\otimes v+ h\otimes w$ since $$f\otimes v+ h\otimes w\neq (f+h)\otimes (v\otimes w).$$

Comment: I am not sure what you are unsure about. You have a vector space with a given proposed action. Show that this is in fact an action which makes it a $\mathbb{C}G$-module.

Comment: I'm not really clear with all this term. How can I do this ? (I don't think I really understand the law)

Comment: You look up the definition of what it means to be a $\mathbb{C}G$-module and check that this thing satisfies the definition. There are no tricks here.

Comment: So I show that $(g+h)\cdot \varphi=g\cdot \varphi+h\cdot \varphi$, $g\cdot (\varphi+\psi)=g\cdot \varphi+g\cdot \psi$, $1_G\cdot \varphi=\varphi$ and $g\cdot Id=g$, and it's finish ?

Comment: Actually, you first look up how (and when) an action of $G$ defines the structure of a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. Then you check that the thing given is an action with these properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "you first look (and when) an action of $G$ defines the structure of a $\mathbb CG$ module ?" (sorry, i'm a little bit a beginner in this, and I'm not very confortable with all these identification).

Comment: Well, the setup is that you are given an action of the group, and it asks you to show that this defines the structure of a $\mathbb{C}G$-module. So you should look up (in whatever notes or book you are using) what the relation is between actions of a group on a vector space and $\mathbb{C}G$-modules.

Comment: There are many equivalence definitions of a module, in fact one of them happens to be what you get when you consider representations, but that's another story. I assume you're reading Fulton and Harris? He doesn't really give a definition of a module or a $\mathbb{C}G-$module. One can think of a module as the action of an abelian group on a ring, in particular vector spaces are the action of $Z$ on the chosen field. One needs that the action is compatible with the ring structure. One can check what requirements we need in any book, Lang or Dummit & Foote.

Comment: @BenjaminGadoua How is one to think of modules as actions of abelian groups on rings? They are precisely the reverse.

Comment: @Tobias whoops, I swapped a bunch of words, haven't had my coffee yet.